# Linux page table

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, virtual-memory, mmu, page-tables

In Linux, there are functions such as pgd_offset, pmd_offset and pte_offset which are used to index to the pgd, pmd and pte. Who calls these functions? Does the MMU use these functions to walk the page tables?

My understanding is that the linux kernel creates a page table for each process and passes the base address of the page table to the page table base register so the MMU can access it. How does the MMU read the page table afterwards? Who uses those pgd_offset, etc functions if the MMU is the one reading the page tables?

Comment: Look [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=pgd_offset).

Answer (score 0):

> How does the MMU read the page table afterwards?

The MMU is using hardware an accelerated method in order to read memory. The actual lookup is architecture-specific: just like the instruction parsing process.

> Who uses those pgd_offset, etc functions if the MMU is the one reading the page tables?

Sometimes, kernel code want to lookup a `struct page` by a virtual address. It must use these functions in order to do this (AFAIK, there is no API for MMU address lookup. Therefore, it must be implemented in the kernel too).